# Force C++ to assign new addresses to arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

It seems that when I pass different integers directly to a function, C++ assigns them the same address as opposed to assigning different addresses to different values. Is this by design, or an optimization that can be turned off? See the code below for an illustration.

```
#include <iostream>

const int *funct(const int &x) { return &x; }

int main() {

  int a = 3, b = 4;
  // different addresses
  std::cout << funct(a) << std::endl;
  std::cout << funct(b) << std::endl;

  // same address
  std::cout << funct(3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << funct(4) << std::endl;
}
```

The bigger context of this question is that I am trying to construct a list of pointers to integers that I would add one by one (similar to `funct(3)`). Since I cannot modify the method definition (similar to `funct`'s), I thought of storing the address of each argument, but they all ended up having the same address.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to take the address of the integer `3`? Not that you can actually do that, but it looks like what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: C++ doesn't work this way. Values don't have addresses. Variables do. `&x` is the address of the variable `x`, not of any value you pass to the function. Different invocations of the function may or may not result in `x` having different addresses. As soon as the function returns, `x` ceases to exist and its address becomes invalid, so you cannot store that address.

Comment: This likely looks like it's working (or not working) because of the magic used to allow a `const` reference to extend the lifespan of of a temporary. Since the variable is temporary its location can be reused over and over.

Comment: I think this isn't actually Undefined Behavior, because he doesn't actually dereference the pointer.  It's _useless_ sure, but not undefined behavior.  There's no temporary lifespan extension happening or needed.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing *"construct a list of pointers to integers that I would add one by one (similar to `funct(3)`)."* You would add [something] one by one to [something] -- what are the somethings? I would have thought "pointers to integers" and "the list", but that is not "similar to `funct(3)`", as ``funct()` does not add anything to anything.

Comment: When you construct your list of pointers to integers, how do you ensure that the pointers remain valid? I would think that ensuring that would sidestep this question. (I guess the question is valid without knowing this, since this aspect is just the context, but knowing this might benefit you.)

Comment: @user4581301 • there is no temporary that is having its lifespan extended in the OP's example.

Comment: I'll accept that there may be no temporary in the strict definition of a temporary variable, but there is an address being returned and I'm interested in knowing what's providing it, even if it's non-portable deep magic.

Comment: If you're storing the address of a temporary such that it outlives the temporary then you're in for trouble when you go to use that address. In that case you presumably need to redesign to store a copy.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The temporary lifespan is certainly extended. That's just not optional; it has to be extended from the subexpression `funct(3)` all the way to after `<< std::endl;`. See 6.7.7/6.9 "exceptions to this lifetime rule"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `const int *funct(const int &x)` takes in a reference that is bound to an `int` variable.

`a` and `b` are `int` variables, so `x` can be bound to them, and they will have distinct memory addresses.

Since the function accepts a **const** reference, that means the compiler will also allow `x` to be bound to a *temporary* `int` variable as well (whereas a **non-const** reference cannot be bound to a temporary).

When you pass in a numeric literal to `x`, like `funct(3)`, the compiler creates a *temporary* `int` variable to hold the literal value.  That *temporary* variable is valid only for the lifetime of the statement that is making the function call, and then the temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed.

As such, when you are making *multiple* calls to `funct()` in *separate* statements, the compiler is free to reuse the same memory for those temporary variables, eg:

```cpp
// same address
std::cout << funct(3) << std::endl;
std::cout << funct(4) << std::endl;
```

Is effectively equivalent to this:

```cpp
// same address
int temp;
{
temp = 3;
std::cout << funct(temp) << std::endl;
}
{
temp = 4;
std::cout << funct(temp) << std::endl;
}
```

However, if you make *multiple* calls to `funct()` in a *single* statement, the compiler will be forced to make separate temporary variables, eg:

```cpp
// different addresses
std::cout << funct(3) << std::endl << funct(4) << std::endl;
```

Is effectively equivalent to this:

```cpp
// different addresses
{
int temp1 = 3;
int temp2 = 4;
std::cout << funct(temp1) << std::endl << funct(temp2) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/w8uLic)

Comment: Are you sure that `cout << funct(3) << funct(4)` is *guaranteed* to print different addresses? It does sound right. What about `cout << funct(3) << funct(3)`?

Comment: @cigien I don't know what the standard says on this, but `funct(3) << funct(4)` should always print different addresses, because this is within a single statement, and `3` and `4` can't share a single temporary since they are in the same scope together. Temporaries stay in scope until the end of the statement that creates them (ie, until the terminating `;`), so `3` and `4` have to be unique temporaries in this case. Now, whether `funct(3) << funct(3)` creates 2 temporaries, or shares 1 temporary, that I don't know. I suspect it depends on the compiler and how well it can optimize.

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense, and I *think* I can figure out what an implementation is likely to do with the code, but I was interested in what the standard says. I think I'll post a language-lawyer question, if I can't find a dupe. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Temporary objects (in modern C++) have some special rules, but unless specifically specified otherwise (see 6.7.7 Temporary objects) the normal object rules would apply. 2 objects cannot overlap unless one is a subobject of the other, or both are subobjects of the same object. The exceptions do not apply here, so the two temporaries cannot overlap. As-if rules still apply, but printing the address makes it observable.

Answer (score 4):

The function

```
const int *funct(const int &x) { return &x; }
```

will return the address of whatever `x` is referencing.

So this will, as you expected, print the address of `a`:

```
std::cout << funct(a) << std::endl;
```

The problem with the expression `funct(3)` is that it is impossible to make a reference of a constant and pass it as a parameter. A constant doesn't have an address, and therefore for practical reasons C++ doesn't support taking a reference of a constant. What C++ actually does support is making a temporary object, initializing it with the value `3`, and taking the reference of *that* object.

Basically, the compiler will, in this case, translate this:

```
std::cout << funct(3) << std::endl;
```

into something equivalent to this:

```
{
  int tmp = 3;
  std::cout << funct(tmp) << std::endl;
}
```

Unless you do something to extend the lifetime of a temporary object, it will go out of scope after the function call (or right before the next sequence point, I am not sure).

Since the temporary created by `3` goes out of scope before you create a temporary from `4`, the memory used by the first temporary may be reused for the second temporary.

Comment: It looks like @Remy clarified the exact lifetime of a temporary.

Comment: "synchronization point"? You might be thinking of sequence points, but those no longer exist. Modern C++ uses "sequenced-before", and in this case the destruction of the temporary object is sequenced-before the next statement. (and sequenced after the return of `funct`, of course)

Comment: @MSalters, it is always nice to have the edge-cases of c++ clarified. Since it was not part of the question I did not look up the exact lifetimes, and left them a little bit vague on purpose. Personally, I would not write code that depend on the lifetimes of temporaries being one way or the other anyhow.